# Reading in Images to an ImageIcon Array List

Tags: java, image, io

I'm trying to read in images from a directory to an array list but I'm having trouble. I can an error and I can't seem to find a solution. I've found a lot of other posts but they are just reading in one specified image.

```
private ArrayList<ImageIcon> images = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner s;
        try {
            s = new Scanner(new File("/images"));
            while(s.hasNext()) {
                images.add(s.hasNext());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Your code seems to be reading the contents of a file. Your question mentions reading from a directory. Are you trying to read the file names from a text file or are you trying to list the contents of a folder?

Comment: Your `new File("/images")` is providing the folder. You need the full path with the image filename.

Comment: You aren't reading anything. `images.add(s.hasNext());` returns whether there's a next or not - but it does read

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to read images whose names are in the text file you are reading, this is how you would create `ImageIcon` objects and add them to the list:

```
        s = new Scanner(new File("/images"));
        while(s.hasNext()) {
            String imageFileName = s.next()
            images.add(new ImageIcon(imageFileName));
        }
```

If instead you're trying to list the contents of a directory, one way is with the `File.listFiles` method.

```
        File directory = new File("/images");
        for (File file : directory.listFiles()) {
            images.add(new ImageIcon(file.getPath()));
        }
```